# Should the [acid-base] tag be applied to carboxylic acids as well?

Tags: discussion, tags

This [search query](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bacid-base%5D%20carboxylic%20acid) yields 33 questions tagged [acid-base] and containing the words "carboxylic acid" in them. (Convenient links to the tag wikis for both [[acid-base]](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tags/acid-base/info) and [[carbonyl-compounds]](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tags/carbonyl-compounds/info))

Note that the tag wiki for [carbonyl-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbonyl-compounds) specifically says:

> Compounds containing the carbonyl group, C=O. The term is commonly used in the restricted sense of aldehydes and ketones, although i**t actually includes carboxylic acids and derivatives.** (*my emphasis*)

So, one may argue that all those 33 questions (and in future, any question about carboxylic acids) should be tagged [carbonyl-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbonyl-compounds) That said, however, carboxylic acids *are* acids also, so the [acid-base](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acid-base) tag could serve them just as well. The current tag usage guidelines do not help resolve this issue.

> Ideally, in case of carboxylic acids, only one of [carbonyl-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbonyl-compounds) or [acid-base](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acid-base) should be used. But which one?

---

<sup>Do note that nearly [68 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bacid-base%5D%20%22ammonia%22%20is%3Aquestion) are tagged [acid-base](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acid-base) and include the word "ammonia" in them, but another [nitrogenous-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nitrogenous-compounds) tag does not exist, so we will have to let them be as they are.</sup>

Comment: I wouldn't add acid base to a question where we weren't talking about acidity/basicity